# How to check if a string column of a data frame matches with a string column of another data frame?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm intending to perform a left join of two data frames using a common character column (let's call this name column). Ideally, all the values in the name column of df1  would have a match with the name column of df2. However, I understand some values may not match exactly but would have a partial match due to some spelling or punctuation error. For eg.  "John Ezekiel" could be spelled as "John Ezekial" in the df1. I want to ensure that each value of the name column in df1 will have a match with some value in the name column of df2. In most cases, there would be an exact match but in the cases where there are not exact matches, I also want to replace those values of df1 with values of df2 that has most partial match. I've illustrated this problem by reproducing

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("John Ezekial","Mary Elizabeth","Fabio Fonini","Gael Monfils","Lucas Pouile"))    
df2 <- data.frame(name=c("Aron Ramsey","John Doe","John Ezekiel","Mary Elizabeth","Fabio Fognini","Gael Monfils","Marin Cilic","Lucas Pouille","Tomas Berdych","Juan Martin Del Potro"),id=1:10)
> df1
            name
1   John Ezekial
2 Mary Elizabeth
3   Fabio Fonini
4   Gael Monfils
5   Lucas Pouile

> df2
                name     id
1            Aron Ramsey  1
2               John Doe  2
3           John Ezekiel  3
4         Mary Elizabeth  4
5          Fabio Fognini  5
6           Gael Monfils  6
7            Marin Cilic  7
8          Lucas Pouille  8
9          Tomas Berdych  9
10 Juan Martin Del Potro 10
```

When df1 is performed left join with df2, I get results as follows:

```
> df1 %>% left_join(df2)
Joining, by = "name"
            name id
1   John Ezekial NA
2 Mary Elizabeth  4
3   Fabio Fonini NA
4   Gael Monfils  6
5   Lucas Pouile NA
```

I want the resulting data frame to be as shown below. The "name" values in df1 should be replaced with "name" values in df2 if there are no exact matches and mapped to their corresponding id's.

```
   >df3
            name id
1   John Ezekiel 3
2 Mary Elizabeth 4
3   Fabio Fognini 5
4   Gael Monfils 6
5   Lucas Pouille 8
```

Comment: (Downvote for apparent  lack of searching effort) I get 33 hits with a search on `[r] merge partial match`  and I get 17 more with `[r] join partial match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Base R you could do something like:

```
 df2[which(adist(df1$name,df2$name)<2,T)[,2],]
                name id
    3   John Ezekiel  3
    4 Mary Elizabeth  4
    5  Fabio Fognini  5
    6   Gael Monfils  6
    8  Lucas Pouille  8
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. However, there are many important columns in df1. Just for the example sake, I simplified into one column. Basically, I want to add `id` column of df2 to the existing columns of df1.  So the rows in the `name` column of df1 that don't get exact match should replace with the ones that have the closest match with the values in the `name` column of df2.

Comment: @MohamadSahil you can be able to edit this code to obtain what you want. In that `which(adist(df1$name,df2$name)<2,T)` gives you the relationship between rows for data1 and data2

Comment: Thanks. I did that. Will `adist()` work well when we're calculating distances between two string vectors with multiple words (3-7)?

Comment: @MohamadSahil Not really. In that case you need vectorized `agrep`